# Get employees and how many employees work for them

Tags: mysql

I want the users(wnr) that are boses(chef) and check how many poeple work for each one.

Example:

user 1 is a boss and is the boss of 3 poeple

user 2 is a boss and is the boss of 4 poeple

user 3 is the boss of user 1 and 2

| wnr(user) | aantal werknemers(amount of employees) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

The table and data I use.

[image: Tabel]

What I tried.

```
SELECT w.wnr, w.wnaam, COUNT(w.wnr) AS 'aantal werknemers'
FROM `werknemer` AS `w`
GROUP BY w.chef
```

But that does seem to get the oposide of what I want.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.wnr, s.wnaam, count(w.wnr) as aantal
FROM werknemer AS s
LEFT JOIN werknemer w ON s.chef = w.wnr
GROUP BY w.wnr, w.wnaam
```

Maybe something like that